How forward sound from OUTPUT LINE to USB?
I'm working on a project to forward audio from AUX to USB.
Requirements:

1 device (ie: phone) with OUTPUT LINE (AUX Jack 3.5 mm Female)
1 custom cable (Stereo AUX Jack 3.5 mm Male to 3 wires (ground, left channel, right channel)
1 Arduino Mega 2560
1 USB Type A to USB
1 computer with following installed softwares:

Arduino IDE or equivalent for Arduino development

Java JDK >= 8

VSCode or equivalent for Java development




The goals of my project is to capture output audio from a device (like a phone or a TV) and send it to a computer.
I've create drivers to forward audio flow but I hear crackling in the speakers, but I can recognize the tune of the music despite the crackling. I'm hearing only cracklings.
My custom cable is plug to the AUX of the device (phone) and the wired of this cable are plugged in the Arduino Mega 2560 Board on ANALOG IN PINS (ground -> GND, left channel -> A0, right channel -> A1).
The USB cable in pluged on the Arduino and on the computer.
The Arduino is on power supply.
I've written a program on the Arduino to forward incoming sound from analog pins to Serial (USB)
I've written this source code that is running on the Arduino:
    const int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;                                  // Fréquence d'échantillonnage en Hz
const unsigned long SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 1000000.0 / SAMPLE_RATE;  // Intervalle d'échantillonnage en microsecondes

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  // Initialiser la communication série à une vitesse plus élevée pour éviter la perte de données
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long lastSampleTime = 0;

  if (micros() - lastSampleTime >= SAMPLE_INTERVAL) {
    lastSampleTime += SAMPLE_INTERVAL;

    // Lire les valeurs analogiques
    int leftSample = analogRead(A0);
    int rightSample = analogRead(A1);

    // Convertir les valeurs analogiques en valeurs audio (-32768 à 32767)
    int16_t leftAudio = map(leftSample, 0, 1023, -32768, 32767);
    int16_t rightAudio = map(rightSample, 0, 1023, -32768, 32767);

    // Envoyer les données audio via le port série (USB) sous forme brute
    Serial.write(0xFF);
    Serial.write(lowByte(leftSample));
    Serial.write(highByte(leftSample));
    Serial.write(lowByte(rightSample));
    Serial.write(highByte(rightSample));
  }
}

And, on the connected computer (to the Arduino), I've create a Java program to read data from USB en send the retrieved audio samples to the output line.
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortDataListener;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortEvent;

import io.nirahtech.soundpack.box.driver.AudioFrame;
import io.nirahtech.soundpack.box.driver.Sample;

public class Jack2Usb2Audio {

    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100; // Fréquence d'échantillonnage en Hz
    private static final int BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 16; // Taille en bits d'un échantillon
    private static final int SAMPLE_SIZE = BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8; // Taille d'un échantillon
    private static final int CHANNELS = 2; // Nombre de canaux (stéréo)
    private static final int FRAME_SIZE = SAMPLE_SIZE * CHANNELS; // Taille du cadre audio en octets, ici = 4
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = FRAME_SIZE * 1024; // Taille du buffer en octets
    private static final int SERIAL_BAUD_RATE = 115200; // Taux de baud
    private static final String SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyACM0"; // Port USB
    private static final byte START_OF_FRAME = (byte) 0xFF;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort serialPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(SERIAL_PORT);
        serialPort.setBaudRate(SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);
        serialPort.setNumDataBits(8);
        serialPort.setNumStopBits(SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT);
        serialPort.setParity(SerialPort.NO_PARITY);

        if (!serialPort.openPort()) {
            System.out.println("Échec de l'ouverture du port.");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Port ouvert avec succès.");

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, BITS_PER_SAMPLE, CHANNELS, true, false);
        try {
            SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            serialPort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
                private boolean isNewSampleCycleStarted = false;
                private List<Byte> cache = new ArrayList<>();
                private AudioFrame audioFrame = new AudioFrame(FRAME_SIZE * 8);

                @Override
                public int getListeningEvents() {
                    return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
                }

                @Override
                public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                    if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                        return;
                    }

                    byte[] newSamples = new byte[serialPort.bytesAvailable()];
                    int totalSamplesRetrieved = serialPort.readBytes(newSamples, newSamples.length);

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalSamplesRetrieved; i++) {
                        final byte receivedSample = newSamples[i];
                        if (receivedSample == START_OF_FRAME) {
                            this.audioFrame = new AudioFrame(FRAME_SIZE * 8);
                        } else {

                            if (!this.isNewSampleCycleStarted) {
                                this.cache.add(receivedSample);
                                this.isNewSampleCycleStarted = true;
                            } else {
                                this.isNewSampleCycleStarted = false;
                                if (!this.cache.isEmpty()) {
                                    final byte previousSample = this.cache.get(0);
                                    this.cache.clear();
                                    final Sample sample = Sample.of(previousSample, receivedSample);
                                    if (!this.audioFrame.hasSpaceLeft()) {
                                        this.audioFrame = new AudioFrame(FRAME_SIZE * 8);
                                    } 
                                    try {
                                        this.audioFrame.addSample(sample);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (!this.audioFrame.hasSpaceLeft()) {
                                byte[] data = this.audioFrame.toBytes();
                                line.write(data, 0, this.audioFrame.getUsedSizeInBits());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            System.out.println("Lecture audio en cours. Appuyez sur Enter pour arrêter.");
            System.in.read();

            line.stop();
            line.close();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            serialPort.closePort();
            System.out.println("Port fermé.");
        }
    }
}

package io.nirahtech.soundpack.box.driver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AudioFrame {
    private final List<Sample> samples;
    private final int maxSizeInBits;

    public AudioFrame(final int sizeInBits) {
        this.maxSizeInBits = sizeInBits;
        this.samples = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getMaxSizeInBits() {
        return this.maxSizeInBits;
    }
    public int getUsedSizeInBits() {
        return (int) this.samples.stream().mapToInt(Sample::getSizeInBits).sum();
    }
    public int getEmptySizeInBits() {
        return this.getMaxSizeInBits() - this.getUsedSizeInBits();
    }
    public boolean hasSpaceLeft() {
        return this.getUsedSizeInBits() < this.getMaxSizeInBits();
    }

    public void addSample(final Sample sample) throws Exception {
        Objects.requireNonNull(sample, "Sample is required for AudioFrame.");
        if (!this.hasSpaceLeft()) {
            throw new Exception("No space left");
        }
        this.samples.add(sample);
    }


    public byte[] toBytes() {
        final byte[] frame = new byte[this.maxSizeInBits];
        int frameIndex = 0;
        for (final Sample sample : this.samples) {
            final byte[] sampleAsBytes = sample.toBytes();
            for (byte sampleBit : sampleAsBytes) {
                frame[frameIndex] = sampleBit;
                frameIndex++;
            }
        }
        return frame;
    }

}

package io.nirahtech.soundpack.box.driver;

public class Sample {

    private final short sample;
    private final byte lowByte;
    private final byte highByte;

    private Sample(final short sample) {
        this.sample = sample;
        this.lowByte = (byte) (this.sample & 0xFF);
        this.highByte = (byte) ((this.sample >> 8) & 0xFF);
    }

    public int getSizeInBits() {
        return 8 * 2;
    }

    public byte getLowByte() {
        return this.lowByte;
    }

    public byte getHighByte() {
        return this.highByte;
    }

    public static final Sample of(final short sample) {
        return new Sample(sample);
    }


    public static final Sample of(final byte lowByte, final byte highByte) {
        final short sample = (short) ((highByte << 8) | (lowByte & 0xFF));
        return new Sample(sample);
    }

    public byte[] toBytes() {
        return new byte[] { this.lowByte, this.highByte };
    }
}




With this code, all what i'm hearing are cracklings that match with tune of the played music on the device (phone).
I think, issues are in the Java source code.
I just want to listen music on the computer with audio incoming from an USB source.

if you want to listen music, why not use the line in jack of the computer or buy a USB dongle 'sound card'?

The analog reading on the Arduino is way too slow to really make for good music.  You can get, like you said, some clicky static that kind of sounds like what you put in.  But if you want to be able to re-create music then you need a much faster ADC.
